# What could be the source of an intermittent, unlocatable rotten egg smell?

Tags: smell

This has happened a few times since I moved into my current house about a year ago; every once in a while, I'll get a faint, brief whiff of rotten egg smell that I am unable to locate. Then, after a few minutes it will be gone and not be smelled again for months.

Today it happened again so I went around sniffing everything to try my best to find the source, trying all the typical emitters. I turned on the hot water and sniffed all the faucets; nothing. I sniffed the sink bowls and the toilets; nothing. I sniffed all the gas appliances as well as the walls where the gas lines drop down from the attic; nothing. And then it was gone again.

Am I going crazy from hydrogen sulfide poisoning? What are some other potential sources I might have missed? Is this the precursor to some gas or plumbing problem that's about to become really really expensive?

Comment: Any pets? How close are neighbors?

Comment: One dog, one non-potty-trained kid :). Neighboring houses are about 30 feet away.

Comment: Do you have a gas stove? Residential gas has a 'rotten egg' smell added to it so you can smell a leak.

Comment: Garbage cans? Decaying chunk of broccoli under the fridge?  Dirty diaper on the baby?  Dog farted?  Pretty hard to tell.

Comment: You may be having [olfactory fatigue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olfactory_fatigue) and unable to smell it (interesting tip from wikipedia: coffee beans can apparently "reset olfaction" -- which may help you track things down). However, gas is a definite possibility. If I were you, I would call your gas company to get them to come check things out -- they likely have an emergency number for this (free) service. If nothing else, you eliminate one possibility and get to sleep better knowing you're not in imminent mortal danger.

Comment: My sister once had well water that had a strong rotten egg smell. Don't know how she lived with it.  Outside chance it's a neighbor watering plants?

Comment: We had a similar problem.  It turned out to be wires in the shower switch.  The problem only happened when someone had an extra long shower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I found it, this time, at least. Turned out to be some rotten, moldy food that managed to get hidden away in the back of an infrequently-used pantry.

Answer (score 0):

In certain areas the water, well water in our case, will have that smell. It is corrected by a water conditioner.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not the water. Our water is municipal and doesn't smell at all.

Comment: Well water is the only time I had heard of this type of issue, I have never heard of that with city water. The answer you had before mine, I did not take the time to see it was your answer. Another "duh" moment for me...

Answer (score 0):

Could be drywall itself.  How old is the house?  [Wallboard contaminated with sulfur compounds was epidemic a few years ago](http://www.williamsmullen.com/news/chinese-drywall-facts-science-and-outlook).

Another occasional source: lead-acid batteries, including sealed batteries, which may be found as backups for garage door openers, alarms, or computer systems.

Comment: Built in 1972. Don't think it's crappy Chinese drywall. No lead-acid batteries lying around.